# How to correctly animate stacking views one after another in Android using handler?

Tags: android, android-layout, animation

I have a LinearLayout with RelativeLayout children. Each RelativeLayout has a background image like a file cabinet. I am trying to animate the drawers dropping down into view one after another with a smooth delay. Everything I have tried plays all animations at once. I have this as my method for animating each drawer:

```
    private void dropAndPause(final RelativeLayout drawer){
    new Handler().postDelayed(new Runnable() {

        @Override
        public void run() {
            animation = AnimationUtils.loadAnimation(MainActivity.this, R.anim.slide_down);
            animation.setStartOffset(750L);
            drawer.startAnimation(animation);
        }
    }, 1200);
}
```

I have also tried this:

```
    View[] views = new View[] { ... };

// 100ms delay between Animations
long delayBetweenAnimations = 100l; 

for(int i = 0; i < views.length; i++) {
    final View view = views[i];

    // We calculate the delay for this Animation, each animation starts 100ms 
    // after the previous one
    int delay = i * delayBetweenAnimations;

    view.postDelayed(new Runnable() {
        @Override
        public void run() {
            Animation animation = AnimationUtils.loadAnimation(context, R.anim.your_animation);    
            view.startAnimation(animation);
        }
    }, delay);
}
```

Instead of `View[] views`, I used this:

```
    View[] drawers = new View[] {
    drawerOne, drawerTwo, drawerThree, drawerFour, drawerFive
};
```

Which plays, again, all of the animations at once. How can I get each "drawer"/view to slide in one at a time? Also, should I have each view as visibility GONE initially?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you want to animate the views inside a layout, then it's much easier to use [layout animations](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/animation/LayoutAnimationController.html). Basically, you need to load an animation, create a `LayoutAnimationController`, set the delay on it, and launch the animation. Here's some sample code.

```
Animation animation = AnimationUtils.loadAnimation(MainActivity.this, R.anim.slide_down);
animation.setStartOffset(750L);

LayoutAnimationController controller = new LayoutAnimationController(animation);
controller.setDelay(0.1F);

viewGroup.setLayoutAnimation(controller);
viewGroup.startLayoutAnimation();
```

The delay here is set as fraction of the animation duration.

Comment: So would I use that on the main layout container or would that be used for each child layout that needs to be animated?

Comment: @SteveC. You set the controller on the layout that contains the views you want to animate sequentially. Don't set it on the child views.

Comment: Another quick question. If LinearLayout is my parent layout, is that the "viewGroup" variable you are referencing?

Comment: @SteveC. Yeah, that would be your `LinearLayout`.

Comment: Thank you for the help. I appreciate it. A quick side question, am I able to play a sound when each view drops into view?

Comment: @SteveC. You can try setting an `AnimationListener` on your `Animation`. Can't vouch that it will work perfectly though, this is a very unusual use case you have.

Comment: That worked perfectly! Thank you again for the extra help :D

Comment: @Malcolm Thanks for the answer. Right now I used the code on my Relative layout which contains a set of text views on exit button click (fade out). The animations work perfectly fine.But I observed that the animation repeats after all the views are done animating. Is there any reason for it?

Comment: @ASN It depends on the XML describing your animation.

Comment: @Malcolm This is my XML layout.
`constraintlayout -> scrollview -> horizontalscrollview -> Framelayout-> Button,ImageView,RelativeLayout,RecyclerView`. I'm applying the animation on the Relative layout which is the child of framelayout

Comment: @ASN On the XML describing your *animation*. There is a parameter which controls repetitions.

Comment: @Malcolm Here is the [link](https://codeshare.io/29meZV) for my XML defining the animation. I haven't mentioned any repetitions anywhere and also when I tried to keep none, there is no option for it. All I can see is `reverse` and `repeat`

Comment: @ASN Then you better ask another question.

Comment: @Malcolm Done posting a new question. Here is the [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49798995/how-to-stop-animating-from-repeating-layout-animation)